# How to deal with multi line SQL Query in Python?(Subquery as variable)

Tags: python, sql

I would like to use some long SQL Query in python like below

```
def method(qa_cursor):
  sub_query = """ Select Some Query 
                  From A
                  where A.id = XXX """

  main_query = """ Select a, b, c ...
                   From B join (""" + sub_query + """) A on ~~~
                   where ~~"""

  qa_cursor.execute(main_query)
  results = qa_cursor.fetchall()
  return results
```

But I am getting errors to use right syntax.
How do i make this possible??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was my typo.. This question is solved. Above How I used is correct